# Positioning div under another div

Tags: html, css

I need to position a div under another div. I found another question on this topic where they suggested I use a main `<div>` and the other `<div>`s as children.
I tried to do that but I can't understand if my part of code that doesn't work or I'm doing it wrong.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
   <div id="uscite" class="block">
      <div id="jp">
         <img src="../img/uscite/scan.png" height="90" width="60" alt="" /><br />uscite jappo
      </div>
      <div id="it">
         <img src="../img/uscite/scan.png" height="90" width="60" alt="" /><br />uscite ita
      </div>
</div>
<div class="block">
   <a href="https://www.facebook.com/fmpitaly"><img src="../img/facebook.png" width="70" height="70" title="Vieni a trovarci su Facebook" alt="Facebook" /></a>
   <a href="https://twitter.com/FMP_Italy"><img src="../img/facebook.png" width="70" height="70" title="Vieni a trovarci su Twuitter" alt="Twitter" /></a>
</div>
```

CSS

```
div#wrapper{
    padding:30px 20px;
    position:absolute;
    right:0;
    border:0px;
}
div#uscite{
    height:35%;
    width:20%;
}
div#jp {
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:left;
    border:0px;
}
div#it {
    text-align: center;
    width:50%;
    height:100%;
    float:right;
    border:0px;
}
.block{
    display:block;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g3do9q0b/

I want a structure like this
[image]

Comment: Did you want something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/rhrutsvc/ ?

Comment: @Josiah That ought to be an answer.

Comment: @colepanike, Looks like Marc has a more applicable answer. Or at least more relevant to this exact question. Mine is a generic case.

Comment: @Josiah Still, this is a better pattern overall. Much cleaner.

Comment: Have you tried something simple like just loading up twitter bootstrap, and set up two rows, one with two cells and one with one cell? http://getbootstrap.com

Comment: @Brian that is way overkill to do this.

Comment: @colepanike Alright, you convinced me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Marc has an answer using your example, but the approach isn't very clean. What you really want is to think about everything in **boxes** when you use HTML+CSS. What you want is two boxes stacked on top of each other, but the top box needs to contain two separate ones. E.G.

```
*----------*
*  1  *  2 *
*     *    *
*----------*
*          *
*     3    *
*          *
*----------*
```

You want the box containing 1 and 2 to be as wide as 3, and of course, 1 and 2 will be half of that width. Thinking of it this way should simplify the development process.

```css
#bottomDiv {
    height: 400px;
    width: 500px;
    background-color: lightblue;
}

#topDiv {
    width: 500px;
    height: 400px;
}

#leftDiv {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    float: left;
}
#rightDiv {
    width: 50%;
    height: 100%;
    background-color: orange;
    float: left;
}
```

```html
<div id="topDiv">
    <div id="leftDiv"> </div>
    <div id="rightDiv"> </div>
</div>
<div id="bottomDiv">
</div>
```

Comment: I understand which is my problem. Is with `position: absolute;` of main `div` because I needed to align this div on the right side of my page. To solve and with this code (that is the same code I used before) I used `float:right;clear:both;`
Thank you to everyone! It's amazing this site!

Comment: To position it on the right side of a page, I added a div before `topDiv` on your code with style `position:absolute; right:0;` but all divs are overlapped. How can I fix it?

Comment: Why are you using `position:absolute;`? You shouldn't need to.

Comment: @Josiah He's trying to get this not as an overall page layout, but a container for a small set of elements on the right side of the page.

Comment: @Shika93 Josiah is right though, you shouldn't need this method. It's generally a very tempting solution to new web designers because you can just put it where you want it, but that's not really what it should be used for. It's better that you learn to understand the flow of the document and how what you're trying to do will fit in. That may take time though, it did for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div id="content">

  <div class="clear">

    <div id="uscite" class="one_half" style="background:blue">
        your content
    </div>
    <div id="it" class="one_half" style="background:red">
        your content
    </div>

  </div>

  <div style="background:orange">
   your content
  </div>

</div>

#content{width:100%;text-align:center}
.one_half{width:50%;float:left}
.clear{overflow:hidden;display:block}
```

Comment: All code and no content makes the OP a dull boy (or girl as the case might be).

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I'll be more descriptive next time.

Answer (score 0):

super simplified, tested only in chrome(html 5)

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="inner">
       <div class="column">
          left
       </div>
       <div class="column">
         right
       </div>
    </div> 
    <div class="footer">
       footer
    </div>
</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/g3do9q0b/10/

Comment: @Josiah beat you to this but this is the right way to do it.

Comment: yeh he has, as i was half way thru it thought i'd post it, think it's a little neater, even if i do say so myself(sad i know)

Comment: I'm afraid I disagree. You didn't include the CSS and you give a solution without explaining the why, though it's obvious the OP is looking for that sort of guidance. @Josiah's is cleaner and explains more what the OP needs to know. Sorry dude.

Comment: there's a jsfiddle link there, i'm a more of a wait and get a response and guide further, your right its does contain more info, just was talking about how it's more palatable to read, but each to their own!

Comment: The reason that there is a prompt for code if you're going to link to a jsfiddle is because off-site code doesn't contribute to the goal of the site of having a repository of good questions with good answers. In the future, you could consider using the new code-snippets feature or at least including all the code from your fiddle.